# Returning Results From A Function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, for-loop, echo

I have created the below function in wordpress in my themes functions.php file.  I want to call this function in my theme template and have the portion of the foreach portion echo'd in my theme template.  How exactly would I do this?  I presume I have to return somthing from the function but I am not sure how to set this up.  Your help is much appreciated.

```
    function geography_navigation($type, $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5) {

    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT wp_eva_geography.$field1, wp_eva_geography.$field2 
    FROM wp_eva_geography
    WHERE wp_eva_geography.$field3='$type' AND wp_eva_geography.$field4='$geo_no_dash';");

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($results as $geography){

        echo "<li> <a href='/$type/$field5/{$geography->$field2}/'>{$geography->$field1}</a></li>";

    }
    echo "</ul>";


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the output into a variable and return it like so:

```
function geography_navigation($type, $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT wp_eva_geography.$field1, wp_eva_geography.$field2
    FROM wp_eva_geography
    WHERE wp_eva_geography.$field3='$type' AND wp_eva_geography.$field4='$geo_no_dash';");

    $output = '<ul>';

    foreach($results as $geography)
    {
        $output .= "<li> <a href='/$type/$field5/{$geography->$field2}/'>{$geography->$field1}</a></li>";
    }

    return $output . '</ul>';
}
```

Please note I have note tested this but believe it should work... Let me know!

Comment: Very good, but you don't know where this fields are coming from. Please, add [**`$wpdb->prepare()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to the Answer, so this code doesn't hangs around in the interwebs as a vector of SQL injections.

Comment: Oh, looks like there's an url coming in too, [`like_escape`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2715) may be of use.

Comment: @brasofilo ... like so?  `$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT wp_eva_geography.$field1, wp_eva_geography.$field2
    FROM wp_eva_geography
    WHERE wp_eva_geography.$field3='$type' AND wp_eva_geography.$field4='$geo_no_dash';"));`

Comment: Like [here](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize), in the function `get_attachment`.

Comment: @cryptic I used your example, but I don't get any results on my page template.  Basically I can calling the function like this <code>geography_navigation("Dealers", "county_short", "county_slug", "type", "state_name", "3");</code> from page.php to build my navigation.  But when I made your changes it solved no links are showing up on my page.php.  Is there something I need to do on page.php?

Comment: @brasofilo thanks for the tip on <code>$wpdb->prepare()</code>, I am going to give it a try.  Should this only be used on sql statements or also when I do a query such as <pre><code>$wp_query = new WP_Query();

  $args = array(
   'post_type' => $posttype,
   'post_status' => array($poststatus),
   'orderby' => 'rand', etc....</pre></code>

Comment: @user1609391 yeah you need to do `echo geography_navigation("Dealers", "county_short", "county_slug", "type", "state_name", "3");` also this is @Devin Walker's answer not mine. I just edited it.  =o)

Comment: @user1609391, only when dealing with `$wpdb` and with user input data (form fields).

Comment: Thank you!  I made that echo change in my page.php, and the opening and closing ul make it to the page from the function but the link does not, any ideas?

Comment: @brasofilo Thank you! Just to clarify one point if I am using wpdb just doing a simple select query and the user is not inputting data from a form there is no reason to use the prepare function?  Or anytime I am using wpdb I should use the prepare function.  Thanks again!

Comment: If you are 100% positive of the input origin (it is fully under your control), no, no need of it. Of course, that's my semi-informed opinion. Don't trust user input, even mine ;)